# Can a lower css specificity overpower a higher one?

Tags: css

Is it or has it ever been possible for a selector like:
`div div div div div div div...` to overpower a single class selector (`.a`)?

I tried it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raoNRd but it seems to crash at higher values.

Comment: never never never ...

Comment: Well, there’s `!important` of course, but that should be used as rarely as possible – in fact, not at all if it can be avoided. Maybe you could tell us what the actual problem is that you want to solve here?

Comment: @CBroe it is meant to understand whether we care about arbitrarily nesting  selectors of a single specificity (i.e. should we not have 30 levels of selectors for the explicit reason that it could overpower a higher selector.)

Comment: Well, keeping your selectors as short as possible and “keeping specificity down” is a general recommendation, a lot of people who you could consider to be experts on the topic have spoken out in favor of that in the recent past.

Comment: waow, you mean you try to reach a div with a class inbricated within 230 parents div ? do you realize that you actually point at nothing if you do not have the HTML structure you are selecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. But you can use `!important` if you need.